# oracle - find record which is the last record

Tags: oracle

I have a query with more than one table with a lot of criteria that gives this result

```sql
select book, max(version)
from a,b  
where condition 1, condition 2... and so on
```

the query is nice , the result is

| book | version |
| --- | --- |
| book1 | 3 |
| book2 | 2 |
| book3 | 1 |

I want to join this result with another table `c`:

| book | version | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| book1 | 1 | id1 |
| book1 | 2 | id2 |
| book1 | 3 | id3 -> I want to join the result with this row |
| book1 | 4 | id4 |
| book2 | 1 | id5 |
| book2 | 2 | id6 -> I want to join the result with this row |
| book3 | 1 | id7 -> I want to join the result with this row |

Comment: Looks like a simple join - where query1.version = c.version and query1.book = c.book

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output. It is not clear how to get version 4 for book1 if max version is 3

Answer (score 0):

If you need to join Table A and Table C.
than try below query:

```
 SELECT a.book, max(version) over
 ( partition by a.book order by a.book) version,c.id
 FROM tablea a, tablec c
 where a.book.c.book
 and a.version=c.version;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query and join:

```sql
SELECT m.book,
       c.version,
       c.id
FROM   (
         select book,
                max(version) AS max_version
         from   a INNER JOIN b  
                ON (condition 1)
         where  condition 2 ... and so one
       ) m
       INNER JOIN c
       ON ( m.book          = c.book 
          AND m.max_version = version )
```